# Confused about meaning of C statment relating to structs

Tags: c

Im having trouble understanding what this statement means, could someone explain it to me.

This is the struct I have:

```
struct dataT
{
    int m;
};

struct stack
{
    int top;
    struct dataT items[STACKSIZE];
} st;
```

This is the statment i am confused about. I dont quite understand what it means:

```
st.items[st.top].m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **st**: An object of type struct stack
> **st.top**: Top of stack
>  **st.items**: Array of stack items
>   **st.items[st.top]**: Top item of stack
>  **st.items[st.top].m**: member `m`
>   of top item of stack

```
              st
  +-----------------------+
  |           top         |  st.top
  +-----------------------+
  | +-------------------+ |
  | |                   |m|  st.item[0]
  | +-------------------+ |
  +-----------------------+
  | +-------------------+ |
  | |                   |m|  st.item[1]
  | +-------------------+ |
  +-----------------------+
  .                       .
  .                       .
  .                       .
  +-----------------------+
  | +-------------------+ |
  | |                   |m| st.item[STACKSIZE - 1]
  | +-------------------+ |
  +-----------------------+
```

if you push `3` and `5` into the stack, it would looks like (Stack is growing downward)

```
              st
  +-----------------------+
  |            1          |  st.top = 1
  +-----------------------+
  |            3          |  st.item[0].m = 3
  +-----------------------+
  |            5          |  st.item[1].m = st.item[st.top].m = 5
  +-----------------------+
  .                       .
  .                       .
  .                       .
  +-----------------------+
  | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |
  +-----------------------+
```

Comment: Good effort to visualize the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Dot (.) is used to access elements of a struct.

> st.items - accesses items[STACKSIZE] array
>
> st.top - accesses the top of st and used as the index

And items array contains dataT and you can access it's only element using

> st.items[st.top].m

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
st.items[st.top].m
```

st denotes an object of type `struct stack` because it was defined in this way

```
struct stack
{
   //...
} st;
```

As `st` is defined as having type of the structure then it has data member with name `items` Here is the structure definition itself.

```
struct stack
{
    int top;
    struct dataT items[STACKSIZE];
};
```

So record `st.items` means access to data member `items` of object `st`.  This data member of the structure is defined as an array

```
struct dataT items[STACKSIZE];
```

with `STACKSIZE` elements.
Thus record `st.items[st.top]` means access to the element with index `st.top` of the array `items`. Each element of the array in turn has type `struct dataT` 
This structure has data member `m`

```
struct dataT
{
    int m;
};
```

Thus record

```
st.items[st.top].m
```

means access to data member `m` of element with index `st.top` of array `items`that is in tirn a data member of object `st`

Answer (score 1):

This statement retrieves the value of the `st.top`th element from `struct stack`. In other words if your implementation increments in decrements the `top` variable of `struct stack` then it will retrieve the last pushed element.